# Is this Wireshark capture of HTTP/2 showing three frames?

Tags: wireshark, http2

I've got a capture of HTTP/2 fetching `https://example.com`.  The three entries on the initial row of the capture are:

```
HyperText Transfer Protocol 2
    Stream: Magic
    Stream: SETTINGS, Stream ID: 0, Length 18
    Stream: WINDOW_UPDATE, Stream ID: 0, Length 4
```

How should I refer to these?  Can I say that they're the three initial frames from `stream 0` and are the `Magic`, `SETTINGS` and `WINDOW_UPDATE` frames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Magic is a not a frame but a special set of bytes, resembling an HTTP/1.1 message. It is sent at the beginning of all HTTP/2 connections to allow HTTP/1.1 servers to reject the connection elegantly with an HTTP/1.1 response so the client knows to revert back to HTTP/1.1. It’s officially known as the [Connection Preface](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.5) but is often referred to as the “Magic” message. As an aside [it has an interesting history](https://blog.jgc.org/2015/11/the-secret-message-hidden-in-every.html).

You can see the Magic message is not a frame as it does not have a stream id nor any of the other necessary [frame headers which define a frame](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4).

The SETTINGS and WINDOW_UPDATE messages are indeed frames and there are [several frame types defined in the HTTP/2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6) and a few more have been added since in extensions.

Comment: Thanks.  Magic isn't in a stream at all, it's before stream 0.

Comment: Just realised who you are.  I'm literally working through your book right now, it's next to me!

Comment: Ha ha! I’m still lurking around the http2 questions to help out and see what else I can learn. Hope you’re finding the book useful!

Comment: Yes, very much so.